# Import model from Activiti modeler to Activiti designer

Tags: eclipse, designer, activiti, bpmn

I'm trying to start with Activiti BPM system. For this task i bought book - "Activiti in Action" by Tijs Rademakers. In section 3.2 there are some samples of creating BPMN process in Modeler and importing created process into Designer.

Everything ok, but when i'm trying to open imported process in Designer - i don't see any graphical objects of the process!

Then i tried to import process from book samples project - and i see such problems.
Is here anyone who catched problem like this and solved it?

Thanks

PS: BPMN files that i'm trying to open can be loaded here:

[File that I created in modeler](http://www.4shared.com/file/qB8py0-h/Simple_Book_Order_Process.html)

[File that I tried to use from book samples](http://www.4shared.com/file/OYHyUbrD/VacationRequest.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your bpmn file with txt editor and manually change attribute `isExecutable` value to `"true"`
inside process tag

```
<process id="sid-2b39da09-bebd-4ec2-a58e-be045cd15c55" isExecutable="true">
```